# Unable to generate access token; IAM returned 403 Forbidden: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken even if service account has it

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-kubernetes-engine

Trying to allow access from my GKE cluster into BigQuery  with an app running in flask and python. When I test it locally I can query BigQuery from my flask app but when I deploy the image with changes to GKE I get this error:

```
  Failed to retrieve 
http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/workload-identity-tutorial@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform 
        from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Status: 403 Response:
    b"Unable to generate access token; IAM returned 403 Forbidden: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
    This error could be caused by a missing IAM policy binding on the target IAM service account.
    For more information, refer to the Workload Identity documentation:
    \\thttps://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#authenticating_to"
```

I have added multiple permissions the service account through which I'm doing workload identity and yet still get same error:

[image]

When I test it locally in my own laptop it works I believe it's because my user account has many more permissions:

[image]